# Sorting/ordering selected features by attribute in QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-attribute, sorting, order, qgsvectorlayer

In a standalone application, I have a layer to which I select some features. Then I need to do an iteration, and I need it to be done in the order of the value of a field/attribute (In my example order by Name of the Cities).

```
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(cities_of_world_file, 'Cities of World', "ogr")
country = 'Spain'
filter = '"Country"=\'%s\' '%country
vLayer.selectByExpression(filter, QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
for feature in vLayer.selectedFeatures():
    print(feature['City'])
```

I think there are two ways:

1. Open the layer ordered, and after that, you make a selection. In SQL when you select records you can say `ORDER BY`, is this order in a `QgsVectorLayer`?
2. Select features and after that, you sort.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use [`addOrderBy`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a58e19ac58496d56971d131a3fa310e91) method of `QgsFeatureRequest` in this way:

```py
request = QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy("City")
for f in vLayer.getSelectedFeatures(request):
    print(f["City"])
```

For a large dataset, using `selectedFeatures()`  may take a long time, Instead, you may consider using the way in this answer.

[`getSelectedFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a89189517ec26fb835739e9e5e4f7bf46) is more memory-friendly when handling large selections.

Comment: @Kadir Thank you for your information. Do you know it's possible open a QgsVectorLayer order by an attribute?. Or you need first open, and after that, make QgsFeatureRequest addOrderBy of all features?

Comment: @Ben W I have followed your suggestion. Always we learn something very new and interesting

Answer (score 10):

Try the snippet below. You can store selected features and an associated attribute as key, value pairs into a dictionary, then sort by the field value. After that, you can access the feature object stored as the key.

```py
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(cities_of_world_file, 'Cities of World', "ogr")

country='Spain'
filter='"Country"=\'%s\' '%country
vLayer.selectByExpression(filter,QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

selected = {f: f['City'] for f in vLayer.selectedFeatures()}
sorted_by_val = {k: v for k, v in sorted(selected.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

for feat, val in sorted_by_val.items():
    print(val)
    # do something with feat
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 9):

This also works:

```
sorted_list = sorted(vLayer.selectedFeatures(), key=lambda el: el['City'])

for feature in sorted_list:
    print(feature['City'])
```

Answer (score 8):

@Ben W, thank you so much, I have marked your answer as correct.

Even so I have found a solution to solve it in one operation. It is a combination of your answer and the instructions on this website to sort a list with a dictionary inside(QgsVectorLayer.selectedFeatures()):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp

```
vLayer= QgsVectorLayer(cities_of_world_file, 'Cities of World', "ogr")
country='Spain'
filter='"Country"=\'%s\' '%country
vLayer.selectByExpression(filter,QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

iter=vLayer.selectedFeatures() # Is a list with a like dictionary inside
iter.sort(key=lambda item: item['City'])

for feature in iter:
    print(feature['City'])
```

Do you Know if it's possible to do my first way:

1.- Open Layer ordered, and after that you make selection. In SQL when you select records you can say ORDER BY, exist this order in a QgsVectorLayer?